# Get values from multiindex object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
--------------------------------
|customer_id | item_id | action|
--------------------------------
|7           | 1       | view  |
--------------------------------
|7           | 1       | view  |
--------------------------------
|7           | 1       | buy   |
--------------------------------
|3           | 5       | view  |
--------------------------------
|3           | 5       | view  |
--------------------------------
```

I am using pandas and I want to have dataframe, in which for every customer there will be every item_id with view and buy count. I did something like this:

```
my_results = result.groupby(['customer_id','item_id','action']).agg({'action': 'count'})
```

I got something like this:

```
--------------------------------------
                                action
--------------------------------------
|customer_id | item_id | action|     |
--------------------------------------
|7           | 1       | view  |    3|
|            -------------------------
|            | 1       | buy   |    1|
--------------------------------------
|3           | 5       | view  |    2|
--------------------------------------
```

Can someone help me how to get list of items for every customer and than number of views for every item in pandas ?

Comment: Can you add expected output with numbers?

Comment: I want to iterate over all items for customer 7 a return true or false if item 1 was viewed and if true I want also get int count of views of item 1.

Comment: OK, so what is expected output from your sample data? How looks new DataFrame? Can you add it to question ?

Comment: There are two tables in question which represents dataframe before and after grouby.

Comment: It seems we dont understand each other. My problem is I dont know what need `Can someone help me how to get list of items for every customer and than number of views for every item in pandas ?` so ask for expected output. You describe it comment but for me is not clear, what is your desired output, why you ask your question. Because it is not `my_results = result.groupby(['customer_id','item_id','action']).agg({'action': 'count'})`, it has to be something else...